# \fancyfoot[CE] in fancyhdr does not work

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm using the following code and I want to put some information "wawa" in even pages and "popo" in odd pages, but the command

`\fancyfoot[CE]{wawa}`

does not work. If I change it to

`\fancyfoot[CO]{wawa}`

then the code

`\fancyfoot[CE]{popo}`

does not work. It seems to me that `CE` are not working here. Someone could help me? Thanks in advance!

THE CODE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage { of} \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[CE]{wawa} \fancyfoot[CO]{popo}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Part A}
\lipsum

\chapter{Part B}
\lipsum

\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, adding `ifthen` package. Then I don't have the `twoside` problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen} % <==============

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage { of} \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{wawa}{popo}} % <==============

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Part A}
\lipsum

\chapter{Part B}
\lipsum

\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

report is by default oneside. Add the twoside option:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,twoside]{report} %<---
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\thepage { of} \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[CE]{wawa} \fancyfoot[CO]{popo}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Part A}
\lipsum

\chapter{Part B}
\lipsum

\label{LastPage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I dont want it, because the margins change in odd and even pages too.

Comment: You will have to. Adjust the margins with geometry.

Comment: I found the solution, as posted above. But thanks anyway!